# ImportError when trying to connect Azure SQL database in LangChain

Tags: sql-server, azure, pymssql, langchain

I have been following this guide to try to query GPT3.5 on my SQL database, hosted on Azure. https://gist.github.com/anderl80/5a593cbfc6d44283864917743557d8da

I am running into an import error on these two lines of code:

```
connection_string = f"mssql+pymssql://{database_user}:{database_password}@{database_server}.database.windows.net:1433/{database_db}"

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(connection_string)
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p28e5.png)

Not sure how to move on from here. Looking for any guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use images for errors, show them as text do we can easily read them

Answer (score 0):

- Used This reference To Connect to SQL using `pymssql` Python driver for [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pymssql?view=sql-server-ver16).
- The error you're encountering seems to be related to the `pymssql` library. Used python --version Python 3.10.9. Install  `pip install pymssql`

```py
import  pymssql
server = 'sampath234.database.windows.net'
username = 'sampath125'
password = 'Sa@80mpath'
database = 'sampath'
try:
conn = pymssql.connect(server=server,  user=username,  password=password,  database=database)
print("Connected to the database successfully!")
conn.close()
except  pymssql.Error as  err:
print("Error:",  err)
```

[image]

- For more details [refer](http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/azure.html) this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pymssql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121212/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-database-using-pymssql-but-can-connect-using-underl).